# Dual Apache installs on Mac

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, mac

I have installed apache via MacPorts but now I seem to have two Apache installations.

The first, the one that comes pre-installed on Mac has configuration at /private/etc/apache2. It can be launched with `sudo apachectl start`. The second, macports version, that I'm using has its configuration at /opt/local/apache2/ and can be started via a custom launchd script.

Could anyone tell me what would be the best approach to sorting this issue? Should I delete the macports version? I initially installed this because I seem to remember that virtualhosts could not be configured on the pre-installed version.

If it's possible I'd rather remove the pre-installed version of Apache.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can just disable the preinstalled version (System Preferences, Sharing, Web Sharing) and it won't get in the way anymore.

Comment: +1 You won't want to remove the built-in install of apache as you may run into issues with future Software Updates. You can always put something like `alias apachectl='/opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl'` in your `~/.bash_profile` so you don't accidentally use the wrong `apachectl`.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-installed version will work just fine and support Virtual Hosts as well. If you are more interested in simply having a web server without having to deal with the issues of configuration etc, I would suggest using MAMP (or MAMP-PRO).

I started using MAMP-PRO a little while back and I will never go back. I don't have to deal with web server issues at all. I simply create my virtual host using the GUI they provide and I am working on web content right away. MAMP is free. If you want to be able to configure virtual hosts using the GUI, you will need MAMP-PRO.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have any issues with virtual hosts with included apache. Look at "/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" example. But  I believe is commented out in "/etc/apache2/httpd.conf" could that be why it didn't work for you, you just need to uncomment that Include line.

Also you should consider using [homebrew](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/homebrew-os-xs-missing-package-manager/) .